# How to avoid widget displacement after making another widget in the same row visible?

Tags: flutter

I've just started learning flutter and for the sake of practice, I'm trying to reproduce iOS contacts app. In this app, when you hit `Edit` button in the app header, `Clear` button on the left becomes visible. Here are two screenshot from my remake:
[image]
Red arrow shows where new button becomes available.
Now when a new buttom becomes available the "All/Missed" widget moves to the right, because it needs to free some space for the new widget. The blue arrow shows where displacement happens.

This is the contents of the child of the Container that holds those controls:

```
child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Visibility(
            visible: _listState == ListState.EDITING,
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text("Clear",
                  style: kAppleActionButtonTextStyle),
              onTap: () {
                print("You pressed clear and eveything will be deleted");
              },
            ),
          ),
          CupertinoSegmentedControl(
            groupValue: _allOrMissedControlGroupValue,
            onValueChanged: (key) {
              print(key);
              if (key == kAllCalls) {
                setState(() {
                  _showMissingOnly = false;
                  _allOrMissedControlGroupValue = kAllCalls;
                });
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  _showMissingOnly = true;
                  _allOrMissedControlGroupValue = kMissedCalls;
                });
              }
            },
            children: {
              kAllCalls: Padding(
                child: Text(kAllCalls),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              ),
              kMissedCalls: Padding(
                child: Text(kMissedCalls),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              ),
            },
          ),
          InkWell(
            child:
                Text(_editButtonText, style: kAppleActionButtonTextStyle),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_listState == ListState.VIEWING) {
                  _listState = ListState.EDITING;
                } else {
                  _listState = ListState.VIEWING;
                }
                _editButtonText = editButtonText[_listState];
                getListOfCalls(_showMissingOnly, _listState);
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
```

How do I avoid this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options:

1- Adding extra properties to your `Visibility` widget.

```
Visibility(
              maintainSize: true,
              maintainAnimation: true,
              maintainState: true,
              visible: _listState == ListState.EDITING,
              child: InkWell(
                child: Text("Clear", style: kAppleActionButtonTextStyle),
                onTap: () {
                  print("You pressed clear and eveything will be deleted");
                },
              ),
            ),
```

2- Using `Opacity` widget.

```
Opacity(
              opacity: _listState == ListState.EDITING ? 1.0 : 0.0,
              child: InkWell(
                child: Text("Clear", style: kAppleActionButtonTextStyle),
                onTap: onTap: _listState == ListState.EDITING
                    ? () {
                        print(
                            "You pressed clear and eveything will be deleted");
                      }
                    : null
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what i needed. Now the placement changes because Edit becomes Done and Done has a different size and moves the control on the left. I'm accepting your answer though. But is there a way to address this new small problem?

Comment: Wrap your InkWell using SizedBox and add a fixed width